# pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GUROBI_RUN'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyomo, gurobi

I met this problem when running the exe after packaging python files using pyinstaller. My python file is an optimization model using **pyomo** package, which calls *gurobi* and *ipopt* solvers. The ipopt solver runs well.
When my gurobi exe program runs, it prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GUROBI_RUN'
ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 136, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 131, in main
...
```

GUROBI_RUN is a py file in path 'C:\Users\******\.conda\envs\gurobi_env\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers'

I have tried several methods including:

1. adding parameters into spec files.

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
pathex=['C:\\Users\\*****\\.conda\\envs\\gurobi_env\\Lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\gurobi900'],
...
```

2. write python code in **main.py** like

```
from pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers import GUROBI_RUN
```

3. adding **hiddenimports** into spec files

```
hiddenimports=['pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.GUROBI_RUN', 'pyomo.solvers', 'pyomo.common.plugins', ...],
```

My current method using pyinstaller is

- run `pyinstaller main.py` in terminal
- a spec file is generated automatically, then revise spec file, including adding **pathex**, adding **hiddenimports**, adding **datas**
- run `pyinstaller main.spec` in terminal
- run `main.exe` in terminal

My operating env is
134 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
134 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
135 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
150 INFO: UPX is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by a very stupid and primal method. Since my package is a file folder instead of a single big exe file, I just try to put the GUROBI_RUN.py file into the file folder, the same level of main.exe. And it works!!! My gurobi program can run regularly in exe now.

Comment: I rechecked my original methods 1, 2, 3, like adding pathx, adding ```from *** import GUROBI_RUN``` or ```import GUROBI_RUN``` after putting the py file next to main.py, and adding hidden imports. All of them are unnecessary once I put GUROBI_RUN.py next to the main.exe in the packaged file folder. All those parameters can be deleted.