# PyInstaller ModuleNotFoundError --paths flag seems to not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I build a simple GUI using Tkinter which I would like to freeze to a standalone executable. I am doing this inside a conda environment. Working with OSX 10.15.7, python 3.7, PyInstaller 4.5.1 and conda 4.10.0.  The folder structure looks like this (simplified):

```
 - ImSep_files
  | - ai4eutils
  | - ImSep
  |  | - ImSep_GUI.py
  | - cameratraps
     | - detection
        | - run_tf_detector.py
```

The script calls other scripts in the ai4eutils and cameratraps folders. If I create a conda env, set the `PYTHONPATH` to include the paths to `ai4eutils` and `cameratraps`, and run `python ImSep_GUI.py`, there is no problem. The GUI opens and functions perfectly. However, if I do exactly the same but run `pyinstaller` instead of `python`, it creates an exe which opens the GUI but throws an error when a button is pressed.

```
  File "/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/cameratraps/detection/run_tf_detector_batch.py", line 56, in <module>
    from detection.run_tf_detector import ImagePathUtils, TFDetector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detection.run_tf_detector'
```

This means that `pyinstaller` cannot find the `run_tf_detector.py` file. I have tried adding the `--paths` flag like:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --name='ImSep' --icon='imgs/logo_small_bg.icns' --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/ai4eutils --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/cameratraps --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/cameratraps/detection ImSep_GUI.py
```

I am aware that there are many topics about this type or error. I have tried many potential solutions, but none seem to work. I have tried the following:

- Using the `--hidden-import` flag, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller) by HHest. If tried different versions: `--hidden-import detection.run_tf_detector`, `--hidden-import cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector`, `--hidden-import cameratraps.detection`, etc.
- Adjusting the `hiddenimports=[],` line with the above paths, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller) by user1251007.
- Adding `sys.path.append(path/to/run_tf_detector.py)` to the top of `ImSep_GUI.py`.
- Downgrading `pyinstaller` to 3.1, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller) by fivef.
- Creating a `hook.py` with `detection.run_tf_detector` the in a `hooks` folder and adding it as `--additional-hooks-dir=hooks`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384288/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror) by Legorooj.
- Loading the needed module as data in the spec file, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301741/how-to-resolve-pyinstaller-module-not-found-error) by Ken4scholars.
- Copy `run_tf_detector.py` into the file folder the same level of `ImSep.exe`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320535/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gurobi-run) by Wayne Zhang.
- Call `pyinstaller` from parent directory, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller) by all or None.
- Install `pyinstaller` in the same directory in which `ImSep_GUI.py` is present, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller) by Habeeb Rahman K T.
- Install `pyinstaller` using `conda-forge` instead of `pip`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411931/using-pyinstaller-with-anaconda-environment) by piping piping.

FYI, this is how I create the environment and run `pyinstaller`:

```
conda create --name imsepcondaenv python=3.7 -y
conda activate imsepcondaenv
pip install tensorflow==1.14 pillow==8.4.0 humanfriendly==10.0 matplotlib==3.4.3 tqdm==4.62.3 jsonpickle==2.0.0 statistics==1.0.3.5 requests==2.26.0
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller -y
cd ~/Applications/ImSep_files
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/ai4eutils:$PWD/cameratraps"
cd ImSep
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --name='ImSep' --icon='imgs/logo_small_bg.icns' --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/ai4eutils --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/cameratraps --paths=/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/cameratraps/detection ImSep_GUI.py
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

PS: For OSX and UNIX users it is possible to get a reproducible example:

```
mkdir ImSep_files
cd ImSep_files
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/cameratraps -b tf1-compat
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/ai4eutils
git clone https://github.com/PetervanLunteren/ImSep.git
curl --output md_v4.1.0.pb https://lilablobssc.blob.core.windows.net/models/camera_traps/megadetector/md_v4.1.0/md_v4.1.0.pb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` is almost always a local minimum. In my experience, it only complicates things in the long run. I would recommend Step 1 is remove `PYTHONPATH` from your workflow and learn about python packagens and editable intsalls. It'll make development much easier in the long run.

`PYTHONPATH` basically started as a way to let "scripts" access other modules without actually installing a package. This made more sense back in the bad old days before virtualenv and conda, but now it is just easier and more organized to just use a package structure.

Try structuring your project like a typical installable python library. E.g.

```
.
├── .git
├── ImSep_files
│  ├── ai4eutils
│  ├── cameratraps
│  │  └── detection
│  │     └── run_tf_detector.py
│  └── ImSep
│     └── ImSep_GUI.py
└── setup.py
```

Make sure you can `pip install .` from your root directory. You should have some top-level package name you import from (in this case I've arbitrarily picked `ImgSep_Files` as your library name, but it could be whatever). Then you ought to be able to always import using either absolute or relative package syntax, like

```
from .detection.run_tf_detector import ImagePathUtils, TFDetector
```

The ultimate test is if you can run `python -m ImSep_files.cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector`. *Without* using `PYTHONPATH`. That means you have your import structured correctly and pyinstaller should have no problem picking up on your dependencies.

Update: here's an example simple package with `setup.py`. I chose setup.py even though that's kinda old school and things are moving towards `pyproject.toml` because there is more documentation out there for this style:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my_package",
    description="An example setup.py",
    license="MIT",
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        "tensorflow",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "run_tf_detector=my_package.scripts.run_tf_detector:main",
            "imsep_gui=my_package.gui.gui:main",
        ]
    },
)
```

Then I have a layout like this:

```
.
└── my_project_name
   ├── .git
   ├── my_package
   │  ├── gui
   │  │  ├── gui.py
   │  │  └── gui_utils.py
   │  ├── scripts
   │  │  └── run_tf_detector.py
   │  └── detection
   │     └── tf_detector.py
   ├── README.md
   ├── setup.py
   └── tests
      └── test_tf_detector.py
```

`my_project_name` is my "repo root". `my_package` is the name of my package. I would import like `from my_package.detection.tf_detector import TFDetector`. In this case, I would put all of the classes and logic in `tf_detector.py`, and then `run_tf_detector.py` is basically just:

```
import sys
from my_package.detection.tf_detector import TFDetector


def main(args=None):
    args = args or sys.argv
    detector = TFDetector()
    detector.detect(args)

if __name__ == __main__:
    main()
```

The GUI follows a simple pattern, with `gui.py` containing the entry point to start the gui. This kind of organization keeps your functional code separate from the nuts and bolts of running as a script. It makes it easy for example to have detectors which run as a CLI script, or as part of a GUI, or as a library you can import.

[Entry points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) are used to tell the installer "this is a thing that you run or a plugin". Some [more](https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2017/07/28/python-entry-points/) info.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. Do I understand correctly that the file structure remains the same, except for adding the `setup.py`? Also, are you sure `setup.py` should be outside `ImSep_files/`? And what do I enter in this `setup.py`? I've run it with `name="ImSep_files"` and `package_dir={"": "cameratraps"}`. Is this correct and are there any fields that I need to adjust for my project? I've followed this tutorial to get a better understanding of packaging python projects packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/. There is no need to to actually upload to pypi.org, right?

Comment: BTW, `pip install .` from `Imsep_files/` works fine. However, the output from `python -m ImSep_files.cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector` is `/Users/peter/anaconda3/envs/imsepcondaenv/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'ImSep_files.cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ImSep_files')`

Comment: What are you calling the "root" of the project? Like if you were to put it in version control, what would be the top level? Maybe ImSep_files is your root, in which case cameratraps is your package. But then that means ImSep should be under cameratraps.  This is a typical way of structuring a python project: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/

Comment: > There is no need to to actually upload to pypi.org, right? Correct. Python packages are just gzip archives or `.whl` files, which are just a kind of binary archive. Python package indexes are essentially just an HTTP server with a directory structure hosting these packages. pypi.org is just the most well known one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far, but I still can't get it not work. setup.py: `"console_scripts": ["ct_utils=my_package.cameratraps.ct_utils:main", "imsep_gui=my_package.ImSep.ImSep_GUI:main","run_tf_detector=my_package.cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector:main"]` but when running `python -m my_package.cameratraps.detection.run_tf_detector` I get `File "/Users/peter/Applications/ImSep_files/my_package/cameratraps/detection/run_tf_detector.py", line 55, in <module> from ct_utils import truncate_float
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ct_utils'`

Comment: So that means you probably need to do a little more reorganization. `ct_utils` should live in your library if that is a necessary component. If you have other code which is "external" to your library, say a script written by a cowoker, you basically have 2 choices: copy it into your library directory structure, or make *that* a library (I don't recommend that in this case, since that means a second library to logistically handle). So basically just make sure everything is in the same library package and follows the right import structure.

Comment: Wow that worked. Thanks for all your elaborate answers!

Comment: You're quite welcome! Python packaging can be tricky - *really tricky* - but it's very rewarding when you get the hang of it.